# Connecting jconsole to tomcat during a benchmark

Tags: java, jmeter, jconsole

I have a simple spring application that I am benchmarking with jmeter.

Do I have to do something to my application to be able to hook into it using jconsole?

I've never used jconsole before, but I think it would be great if I can view the # of objects created and memory consumption and the behaviour of the GC etc.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

JConsole is an old stuff, use VisualVM. Look at [this discussion](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1890431/profile-tomcat-application-with-visualvm) to see how to connect VisualVM to your Tomcat.

And no, you don't have to do anything to your application to be able to profile it with any (I hope) profiler.