# My website stopped again and again due to memory leak

Tags: java, spring, spring-mvc, memory-leaks, tomcat7

I have developed a website in Java Spring. It has very good foot fall around 5000/-day. I have deployed it on Java Apache Tomcat server. On daily basis it stops 2-3 times. I am getting memory leak issue but I am unable to identify where this leak issue or why this is happening.

I am getting following log from Apache:

```
SEVERE: The web application [ ] created a ThreadLocal with key of type [org.springframework.core.NamedThreadLocal] (value [Locale context]) and a value of type [org.springframework.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet$1] (value [en_US]) but failed to remove it when the web application was stopped. Threads are going to be renewed over time to try and avoid a probable memory leak.
Feb 22, 2015 8:07:03 AM org.apache.catalina.loader.WebappClassLoader checkThreadLocalMapForLeaks
SEVERE: The web application [ ] created a ThreadLocal with key of type [org.springframework.core.NamedThreadLocal] (value [Request attributes]) and a value of type [org.springframework.web.context.request.ServletRequestAttributes] (value [org.apache.catalina.connector.RequestFacade@25494fc]) but failed to remove it when the web application was stopped. Threads are going to be renewed over time to try and avoid a probable memory leak.
Feb 22, 2015 8:07:03 AM org.apache.catalina.loader.WebappClassLoader checkThreadLocalMapForLeaks
SEVERE: The web application [ ] created a ThreadLocal with key of type [org.springframework.core.NamedThreadLocal] (value [Locale context]) and a value of type [org.springframework.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet$1] (value [en_US]) but failed to remove it when the web application was stopped. Threads are going to be renewed over time to try and avoid a probable memory leak.
```

Comment: This might help you on the right path towards finding the leak. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1890431/profile-tomcat-application-with-visualvm

Comment: JProfiler is a tool that might help to find the leak, if it exists.

Comment: @LukeSpringWalker No I don't have that tool. Can you guide me how I can use that?

Comment: @CodeHunter I used long time ago, I don't remember how, but it's very intuitive. There are some videos and tutorials about it.